# Rotating Header Images

Tags: php, theme-development, themes

I'm trying to set up a Random Image Rotator into the header of a Wordpress custom theme using the Wordpress method:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Headers#Rotating_Header_Images

This seems to work fine on Mac Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

However I am getting differing results on Windows OS in different browsers. In IE11, Edge and some versions of Firefox the image does not change at all if you refresh or change the page.

[Demo](http://host.sonspring.com/css-rotator/)

I've tried searching around but can't find anyone who has pointed out this issue so far. Any advice please?

---

Comment: That script is even older than WordPress itself.. :D On topic, probably some caching issue, it might help to add some "random" component, like a time stamp, to the image name, to prevent caching. Search the internet you'll find solutions.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work in Edge, but it's also a javascript problem, not a WordPress issue.

Comment: You might have better luck with [Custom Header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) and [`get_random_header()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_random_header_image)

Comment: Greg, thanks for the info. I now have something working, the links and content were just what I needed. ialocin is right, the script is just old. Thanks again